# What C++ libraries can I use to download HTTP web-page, other than libcurl?

Tags: c++, http

I would also like to have an opportunity to add/modify HTTP GET headers, but basically I just need to download a page with given URL.

P. S. The only reason I'm searching for an alternative to *libcurl* is it doesn't give me the kind of download speeds I need.

Comment: What's wrong with libcurl? Besides, do you need a platform-independent library or it can be platform-specific?

Comment: Good point. Cross-platform is preferred, but if there's something for windows only - I'd test it.

Comment: libcurl is very, very cross-platform, it has a permissive license, and has the benefit of being well-established. Do you have some other requirements that it doesn't meet? (If you define your requirements, people can make better suggestions.)

Comment: @Matteo Italia: There's nothing wrong with libcurl except I can't squeeze any decent performance (download speed) out of it, even guys from libcurl's mailing list couldn't help me.

Comment: wondering why nobody mentioned cpp-netlib which is part of boost now !!

Comment: cpp-netlib has been improving at a steady pace and it is probably the best option already. However, it does *not* appear to be part of Boost yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Poco C++](http://pocoproject.org/) has a [HTTPClient](http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Net.HTTPClientSession.html) class that is fairly easy to use. [Here](http://pocoproject.org/slides/200-Network.pdf) is their Networking tutorial. Poco C++ is also cross platform.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251361/boost-asio-based-http-client-library-like-libcurl) are some boost like recommendations from SO.

**EDIT :** If you haven't looked at [Qt](https://www.qt.io/), they have a [QNetworkRequest](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkrequest.html) class. Seems a bit lower level than the Poco client, but might suit your needs. [Here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-http-example.html) is an example using it.

Comment: +1 for my preferred answer + good links to hands-on starting points

Comment: Thanks! :) I had to a small problem with the `HTTPClient` link, but I fixed that.

Answer (score 2):

To add to the other answers, if you target only Windows you can use the the urlmon functions (included in Windows), like [URLDownloadToFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775123%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) or [URLOpenBlockingStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775127%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

[libwww](http://www.w3.org/Library) looks like it might fit what you are looking for.