# WebClient in C++

Tags: c++, html, .net, webclient

I'm writing a program that needs to be able to read in HTML source code into a string.

I've read about WebClient for C# but I need to write my program in C++ and I'm not sure how to do that (I've never used WebClient before).

Can anyone give me a simple C++ example program showing me how to get HTML source code into a string using WebClient? (or any better method)

Thanks.

Comment: What do you have to do with the HTML once you have it in memory?  Is it really just reading it, or do you need to parse the structure?

Comment: I'm reading it into a string and searching through the string for numbers (but i'm fine with that part) its just getting the source code into the string that i don't know how to do

Comment: Are you reading it from a file or off the web?

Comment: Straight off the web into a string, or straight off the web into a file

Comment: 2 people have already answered how to go from a file into ram, you can use curl to get it from the web into a file:  http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8245444/490018

Answer (score 2):

See this page, *A Fully Featured Windows HTTP Wrapper in C++*:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/66625/A-Fully-Featured-Windows-HTTP-Wrapper-in-C

Sample code from that page, looks like what you want:

```
void ProgressTest(void)
{
    // Set URL and call back function.
    WinHttpClient client(L"http://www.codeproject.com/", ProgressProc);
    client.SendHttpRequest();
    wstring httpResponseHeader = client.GetResponseHeader();
    wstring httpResponseContent = client.GetResponseContent();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I don't know what webclient for c# is. To read a file into a string-:

```
 std::ifstream ifs("webpage.html");
 std::string str;
 str.assign((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs)),
            (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));
```

Comment: as the question title suggests, the op wants to access the file using a http request, hence the need to get a webclient.