# How can I make a POST on http using boost::asio?

Tags: c++, http, post, boost, boost-asio

Hello I'm trying to do a POST using boost::asio but I'm unable to do so. I'm looking at this example code: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/http/client/sync_client.cpp How can I make this code using POST instead of GET?

Comment: I think cpp-netlib might be of use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251361/boost-asio-based-http-client-library-like-libcurl

Answer (score 0):

asio works on the transportation layer (e.g. tcp sockets) not on the application level. Your solution would be more maintainable if you select a wide-spread http client library instead of implementing the http protocol yourself.

curl, poco and cpp-netlib is mentioned frequently here at SO but there are tons of available clients.

Have a look at these comparisons:

- http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/competitors.html
- [C/C++ HTTP Client Library for Embedded Projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23842394/c-c-http-client-library-for-embedded-projects)
- http://kukuruku.co/hub/cpp/a-cheat-sheet-for-http-libraries-in-c