# connect to website purely by raw socket connection

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, http, c++11

**Language** -> C++11 or C++98 {NOT C}
**OS** -> Linux embedded system
**Restriction**-> NO use of any 3rd party library. 
**Overview** -> to establish connection with website.
I have an Linux  embedded system and Its not allowed to download any libraries like poco or libcurl or boost to establish connection with website and extract information. So I am wondering if someone can direct me to how to establish connection purely by raw sockets in C++ [not c] and retrieve information from page.

Parsing the information and retrieving exact information is not a challenge for me, my main problem is how would I establish connection over http protocol. If I am right , to connect to website I need http protocol rather than TCP/IP.
Could some one please point me to right direction.
Thanks

Comment: HTTP is a layer on-top of TCP/IP. The TCP/IP layer is for transport. The HTTP layer is for how the data is interpreted.

Comment: Why not C. If you are talking raw sockets the best API is there.

Comment: You'll need to use Linux socket-related syscalls and do your own HTTP header parsing.

Comment: Is this your homework?

Comment: @n.m No mate. its task,I have been active in forum for many years so I cant be student. Also say even if its homework , there is no harm in asking or seeking for advices. Had someone ask for code without trying then its wrong

Comment: There is nothing wrong with homeworks, however artificial restrictions like "NOT C" and "not allowed to download any libraries" make little sense outside of typical homework environments.

Comment: @n.m, well yeah your right , your  points make sense . But I assure its not homework. Also just a small hint from Loki and Arcinde made me to think in different direction and I think I can solve the issue . Earlier I googled and all I was getting is using libcurl etc but their bit of advice helped me and I am sure i wil resolve my issues

Comment: I'm not out to disqualify the question or blame you for whatever, I'm just trying to understand your exact situation.

Comment: Tutorials on RAW sockets for `C` will work just fine in `C++` (most likely). Do you actually mean RAW sockets or do you just mean sockets rather than a library?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23842394/c-c-http-client-library-for-embedded-projects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can communicate with `HTTP` with raw TCP `socket`.Since you didn't provide code, I can't provide code either. If you already know how to connect, send and receive data from server, it should be easy. Just follow the steps below.
Let's assume you want to connect to `www.cnn.com`.

**1**. Convert the the domain name of the website to an IP Address.

**2**. Connect to that IP address with port **80**.

**3**. Send the string `GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.cnn.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n`

**4**. Read from the socket/server. If the server is available, it will respond with the page or html code on that webpage.

**5**. Close socket connection.

Note that some websites will not respond or will even block you if you don't provide the `User-Agent`/**Web browser** name you are using.

To fix this, in step add, add `User-Agent:MyBrowserName \r\n` header to the string. You can fake browsers. You must put `\r\n` after each header.

For example, the Chrome browser I am using is *Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.97 Safari/537.36*.

Your new string that will be sent in Step 3 should look something like this `GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.cnn.com\r\nConnection: close\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.97 Safari/537.36\r\n\r\n`. You should notice that there is `\r\n` after each header.  The last header ends with `\r\n\r\n` instead of `\r\n`.

Other useful headers are `Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n` , `Accept-Language: en-us\r\n`, `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n` ,

Replace port **80** with **443** if the website is `https` instead of `http`. Things get complicated from here because you have to implement the `SSL` protocol.

Assuming you want to access page in another directory instead of the home page and the url is http://www.cnn.com/2016/05/13/health/healthy-eating-quiz/index.html

The string to send should look like this:

`GET /2016/05/13/health/healthy-eating-quiz/index.html HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.cnn.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n`

If you are using proxy, you have to put the whole url after `GET` command:

`GET GET http://www.cnn.com/2016/05/13/health/healthy-eating-quiz/index.html HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.cnn.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n`

Comment: thanks mate , thats a great help. based on your explanation , I have created it.

Comment: @samprat Nice. Glad I was able to help.