# HTTP/2 on FreeRTOS

Tags: http, freertos

I am wondering is there HTTP/2 open source code/library (I will more likely to use it as client) that's light weighted, written in C, and runs on freertos?

I have did research of my own ([C/C++ HTTP Client Library for Embedded Projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23842394/c-c-http-client-library-for-embedded-projects)) and I also came to know about the demo code given by the [FreeRTOS + TCP demo from FreeRTOS's TCP stack](http://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS-Plus/FreeRTOS_Plus_TCP/HTTP_web_Server.html).

I am wondering if you guys know any open source code/library that's light weighted, written in C, and runs FreeRTOS and implements HTTP/2?