# Looking for Http2 client for embedded Linux low horse power device

Tags: c++, http2

I am looking for "simple" Http2 client code/library for low horse power linux device which (will be running on m4 cortex). The lighter it's, the better. As a first point, I am looking for something that's off-the-shelve.

I have spent few hours google-ing around the web. The best resource that I found is [C/C++ HTTP Client Library for Embedded Projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23842394/c-c-http-client-library-for-embedded-projects). The suggested library is implemented in C++.

> - [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) - too heavyweight
> - [poco](http://pocoproject.org/) - too heavyweight
> - [neon](http://www.webdav.org/neon/) - GPL
> - [qlibc](http://www.qdecoder.org/wiki/qlibc) - relies on POSIX libraries
> - [cpp-netlib](http://cpp-netlib.org/) - relies on Boost libraries
> - [serf](https://code.google.com/p/serf/) - relies on the Apache Portable Runtime library
> - [urdl](http://think-async.com/Urdl/doc/html/index.html) - relies on Boost libraries
> - [HTTP Client C API](http://chttpclient.sourceforge.net/) - promising but requires a C++ wrapper

I am wondering if you guys have any idea?

Comment: I don't think software has a weight at all. But I'd accept if a quantum physician can prove me wrong (I'm not sure I'll understand the proof, though). And the Cortex-M4 (I assume that's what you mean) is not capable to run a Linux system, so that does not make sense either!