# Library to download a file from a web site?

Tags: c++, c, http

Say I have this file:
http://www.example.com/somepic.png

Is there a cross platform C or C++ library that could easily allow me to download it to a specified directory?

Thanks

Comment: [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251361/boost-asio-based-http-client-library-like-libcurl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/) to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Besides itself, the [GNU libmicrohttpd](http://www.gnu.org/software/libmicrohttpd/) Web site lists several [alternatives](http://www.gnu.org/software/libmicrohttpd/#alternatives).