# Does Boost C++ have a Download/Web Library

Tags: c++, http, boost, download

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Boost.ASIO-based HTTP client library (like libcurl)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251361/boost-asio-based-http-client-library-like-libcurl)

Does Boost C++ have a namespace/library that downloads a file via HTTP or FTP? I am writting an application that will download an XML file.

The application needs to work on Windows XP and up which is why I am looking at Boost C++ because of portability and speed of development.

If Boost doesn't have a download library, do you know of a library that can download a file and is Cross Windows Version compatible?

Answer (score 2):

[Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio.html) may be what you want.

There is another good C++ Library named C++ Poco, which also provides HTTP/FTP download functionality.