# Retriving website data with C++

Tags: c++, c

I want to retrieve content from any website, which means I want to write a code in C++ language  which download the content of any website and then save it to notepad file or any other supported file format.

Can anyone suggest about this?

Comment: I wonder how this question is related to almost every language starting with `C`

Comment: We can only suggest you to write some code, make a prototype, class diagram. Your program will need a good xml parser such as `libxml`., or just a one from `boost`. There you go.

Comment: You can use the CURL C  library in C++. Job done.

Comment: I was about to say about curl which has been just mentioned by @juanchopanza

Comment: @RafafTahsin keep us updated.

Comment: Why do you need to write your own app for this? `wget` will do this wihtout writing any code...

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is good framework/library for C/C++ web programming?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453665/what-is-good-framework-library-for-c-c-web-programming)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251361/boost-asio-based-http-client-library-like-libcurl). In the answers you will find multiple libraries which implement HTTP clients in `C++`.

- [Boost HTTP](https://github.com/BoostGSoC14/boost.http)
- [The C++ Network Library Project](http://cpp-netlib.org/)
- And many more.

In the documentations (for example [here](http://cpp-netlib.org/0.11.1/index.html)) you will find many examples.

```
using namespace boost::network;
using namespace boost::network::http;

client::request request_("http://127.0.0.1:8000/");
request_ << header("Connection", "close");
client client_;
client::response response_ = client_.get(request_);
std::string body_ = body(response_);
```